# Invariant Theory over finite adeles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Classical invariant theory, among the other things, classifies polynomial functions over a vector space $V$ endowed with a quadratic form $Q$ which are invariant under the action of $SO(V,Q)$.

I am interested in the following problems (I have no idea if it has already been solved, or maybe is open and very difficult, any reference is welcome).

Let $\Lambda$ be a free group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^N$. Let $Q$ be a quadratic from over $\Lambda$, say integer valued, positive definite, even and unimodular (or add any properties you like). We tensor up $\Lambda$ by the the finite adeles and extend the quadratic form. Now, consider the ring of Schwartz functions over $\Lambda\otimes \mathbb{A}_f$. Which of them are invariant under the action of $SO(Q,\mathbb{Q})$??

thanks